# подключить плагин при заходе на определенную страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

Ситуация такая. Есть сайт, на котором несколько страниц, а так же есть определенный плагин, который нужно подключить только при посещении определенной страницы, и так же отключать плагин, если это не уже иная страница. Делается в джумла, логика обращения к странице уже есть, через if. Т.е. грубо говоря, есть 10 страниц, заходим на 5-ю, плагин подключается (в head), заходим на любую иную, то плагин "прибивается". Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил следующим образом:

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "путь_до_файла";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```